# $f$ is entire, $f(0)=f'(0)=0$, and $D= \{|z| \lt R\}$. $\forall z \in D: |f(z)| \leq M$. Prove $\forall z \in D: |f(z)| \leq \frac{M|z|^2}{R^2} $

Tags: complex-analysis

$f$ is entire, $f(0)=f'(0)=0$, and $D= \{|z| \lt R\}$. $\forall z \in D: |f(z)| \leq M$. Prove $\forall z \in D: |f(z)| \leq \frac{M|z|^2}{R^2} $

**What I tried so far:**

Define $g(z)=\frac {f(z)}{z^2}$. This function is entire since $g(0)=\frac {f''(0)}{2}$.

Set a circle $C_r$ centered at $z=0$ with radius $r \lt R$. By Cauchy Integral Formula we get that: $$|g(0)|\leq \frac{1}{2\pi} |\int _{Cr} \frac{g(z)}{z} dz| =\frac{1}{2\pi} |\int _{Cr} \frac{f(z)}{z^3} dz| \leq \frac{1}{2\pi} 2\pi r \cdot max_{z \in C_r} \frac {1}{z^3} \cdot max_{z \in C_r} f(z) \leq \\ \leq r \cdot \frac {1}{r^3}{M}=\frac {M}{r^2}$$

Set $r \rightarrow R$ and multiply both sides with $|z|^2$, and we get $|f(0)| \leq  \frac{M|z|^2}{R^2}$.

But I just can't seem to prove it in general...

Any assistance will be great!

Comment: Have you met Schwarz's lemma?

Comment: Sadly I have not...

Comment: and why did you apply Cauchy only at $0$, the general formula for $g(z)$ does not work ?

Comment: If I would have applied it at some point $z_0$, I would've need to sort out $max _{z \in C_r} \frac {1}{z^2(z-z_0)}$. I'm not sure whether it is indeed $\frac {1}{r^3}$...

Comment: Define $g$ as you did. Apply the Maximum Modulus Theorem...

Comment: But the issue is that $|f(z)| \leq M$ only when $|z| \lt R$. Maybe when $|z|=R$, $|f(z)| > M$?

Comment: So for any point $w \in D$, choose $r$ such that $|w| < r < R$, and apply the Maximum Modulus Theorem on $\{z \mid |z| < r\}$.

Comment: And then let $r\to R$.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you. But, you can only say that $max_ {z \in C_r} |f(z)| \leq M$, and not strictly equal, right?

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify things by observing that if $|f(z)|\le M$ on an open disk, then the same inequality holds on the closed disk. Non-strict inequalities for a continuous function propagate to the closure of the set, by continuity.

Then apply the maximum principle to $f(z)/z^2$ and you're done.

The resulting inequality indeed allows an equality case; after all,  you could have $f(z) = Mz^2/R^2$.